# como imprimir div al lado del otro con un foreach?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap

tengo el siguiente problema. tengo este codigo php

```
function consultPro() {
        $db=Conexion::conectar();

        $sql=$db->query("SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.nombre, producto.id_categoria, datos_producto.precio, datos_producto.image, categoria_producto.categoria FROM producto INNER JOIN datos_producto ON producto.id_producto=datos_producto.id_producto INNER JOIN categoria_producto ON producto.id_categoria=categoria_producto.id_categoria");
        $sql->execute();

    // while ($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //   $fila=$row;
    // }
    return $sql;


    }
```

ejecucion de consulta

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id_cliente'])){
      $fila=consultPro(); 
 ?>

  <br>
    <?php foreach ($fila as $row) {
        # code...
     ?>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
             <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                     <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary"><?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></strong>
                     <h3 class="mb-0">
                       <a class="text-dark" href="#"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></a>
                     </h3>
                     <div class="mb-1 text-muted"> <h4 class="card-title pricing-card-title">BsF.<small class="text-muted"><?php echo $row['precio']; ?></small></h4></div>

                      <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary" value="Comprar">
                   </div>
                   <img width="300" height="300" class="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-xs-block d-sm-block d-lg-block" src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                 </div>
          </div>  
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
<?php 


} else{ header('location:index.php');}
```

pero me tira los div en forma de lista, es decir, uno de bajo del otro. pero, quiero que se impriman dos por fila.

para los estilos, utilizo **Bootstrap 4**. por eso, le doy un ancho de 6. pero no logro que se impriman dos por fila. Como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el div contenedor fuera del foreach, de esta manera el contenedor no se repetira, adentro del foreach.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
<?php foreach ($fila as $row) {
    # code...
 ?>     
  <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
           ......................
<?php } ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás ciclando con todo y contenedor, entonces siempre te va a crear uno sobre otro por que todos son contenedores.
Aquí debes sacar el contenedor de `foreach`. Te dejo el ejemplo un poco modificado, concatené todo en una cadena y al final le hice `echo`

```
<?php 
if( isset( $_SESSION['id_cliente'] ) ){

    $fila=consultPro(); 
    $html = '
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mb-2">';
    foreach ($fila as $row) {
        $html.='
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
              <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">'. $row['categoria'] .'</strong>
              <h3 class="mb-0"><a class="text-dark" href="#">'. $row['nombre'] .'</a></h3>
              <div class="mb-1 text-muted">
                <h4 class="card-title pricing-card-title">BsF.<small class="text-muted">'. $row['precio'] .'</small></h4></div>
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary" value="Comprar">
            </div>
            <img width="300" height="300" class="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-xs-block d-sm-block d-lg-block" src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="Card image cap">
          </div>
        </div>';
   }
   $html.='  
    </div>
   </div>';

   echo $html;


} 

else{ 
  header('location:index.php');
}
```